# I'm trying to generate two UPPERCASE letters in password generator at python by upper function but it doesn't work

Tags: python, function, uppercase, password-generator

I created a function starts with

```
def letter_def(letter):
letter_ = randint(1, 26)
if letter_ == 1:
    letter = "a"
elif letter_ == 2:
    letter = "b"
```

and ends with

```
elif letter_ == 25:
    letter = "y"
elif letter_ == 26:
    letter = "z"
return letter
```

then i tried to call this function by

```
password = {symbol_def(symbol_1), symbol_def(symbol_2), number_def(number_1), number_def(number_2),
                letter_def(Capital_1.upper()), letter_def(Capital_2.upper()), letter_def(letter_1),
                letter_def(letter_2), letter_def(letter_3), letter_def(letter_4)}
    password = list(password)
    print("\nyour password is: " + str(password[0]) + str(password[1]) + str(password[2]) + str(password[3]) +
          str(password[4]) + str(password[5]) + str(password[6]) + str(password[7]) + str(password[8]) +
          str(password[9]) + "\n")
```

and focus on this line

```
letter_def(Capital_1.upper()), letter_def(Capital_2.upper())
```

but there isn't any UPPERCASE letters in the generated password as

```
your password is: 9fk)b4}qoa
```

so should I make another function for upper cases or there is solution for this problem

Comment: whats `symbol_def`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your code. Your only requirement is that the password should contain two random uppercase letters amongst other lowercase, digits and specials?

Comment: A 26-letter if-elseif is quite ugly. Just add the letter value to the character 'a'.

Comment: Just a side note: you can use random.choice(string. ascii_letters) to get a random letter instead of multiple if\else

Comment: you can try something like ```print("Your password is: " + ''.join([i for i in [random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+=-~`[]\\;,./{}|:\"\'<>?') for j in range(10)]]))```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to generate a random password with two and only two random uppercase letters in it somewhere, you can do this:

```py
import random
import string


def generate_password(length=10):
    two_random_uppercase = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2)
    other_random_characters = random.choices(
        string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation,
        k=length - 2,
    )

    password = "".join(
        random.sample(two_random_uppercase + other_random_characters, k=length)
    )

    return password


print(generate_password())
```

First you take two random uppercase letters, then you take a number of random characters consisting of lowercase, digits and specials.

Then you add them together and get a randomly shuffled sample from them, join the random sequence of characters together, and your password is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are trying to generate a random password this way.
However I believe to fix your problem you probably need to call letter_def(Capital_1).upper()
That will make the letter capitalise after you randomly pick a letter.

If you just want to generate a random password something like this would work:

```
import string
import random

def gen_password(stringLength=10):
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    password = ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))
```